# Sharing menu bar between activities

Tags: android, button, android-activity, menu, share

I have a menu bar on my app, that I need to share between 5 of my activities. My menu bar (= 5 buttons allowing to switch between activities) has exactly the same UI and the same behavior for any activity so I would like to share both menu bar XML view code and controller code.

I already found a way to share the XML code using [Reusable UI Components](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts) but I can't find a way to share the controller code that controls the menu bar buttons clicks.

Note: my menu bar is a custom-made one, not the Android [Options Menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think this link can help u so visit this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3611361/1023138

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best solution is to use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html), using the [Android Support v4 library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can take one activity with you menu bar implemented simply, and then you can use that class to extend each of you activity instead of acivity

suppose your base activity looks as below:
BaseActivity extends Activity

and after this you can extends all your five activity with BaseActivity

Comment: I did it but which layout do you set on `setContentView()` in the BaseActivity then after???

Comment: is it possible to use "Tab Group"

Comment: I don't know. But can you please explain me more about the solution you proposed?

Comment: Here is [document link of "Tab Layout"](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html). You can implement this for your solution if it fit in your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try creating your own View class.  Say the root tag of your menu bar is RelativeLayout.

```
public class MenubarView extends RelativeLayout {
    public MenubarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        // inflates menubar.xml into this view
        // (note: menubar's root view should probably be a 'merge' tag)
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.menubar, this);
    }

    // controller code
}
```

Then in your xml, just embed your custom view like so:

```
<LinearLayout
   ... />

    <com.your.package.MenubarView
        ... />

</LinearLayout>
```