# Using a single Dialog code in multi classes

Tags: android, dialog

I have a alertdialog that I know I will be using in multi classes thoughout my app and you can tell I would rather place it in its own class and call it when nessary. Its a simple text field and ok/cancel buttons. I always want to pass some text into it and after the user has clicked OK I want a variable to be updated with the updated text string

Whats the best way at converting this code so it can be used else where

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);

editTextfield = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.comment_text);
editTextfield.setText(text);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(layout);
builder.setTitle(R.string.title);

builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

        text = editTextfield.getText().toString();

            removeDialog(DIALOG);

});
builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

           removeDialog(DIALOG);

    }
});

AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
return dialog;
```

Thanks for you time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out this tutorial it shows you exactly how to do what you are trying to do. You have to extend the Dialog class.

[Custom Dailog class](http://blog.androgames.net/10/custom-android-dialog/)

Answer (score 1):

I did exactly that. Created a `ConfirmDialog` class that creates the AlertDialog.Builder in its constructor, and delegates the `show` call in its own `show` method. Just pass a `parent` parameter (the calling activity), and use it to do all your resources gathering.

Have a String variable on that class, and a getter to get it.

Then you can do something like (from any activity):

```
....
final ConfirmDialog myDialog = new ConfirmDialog(initialText);
myDialog.show();
....
```

And when you need the text

```
myDialog.getText();
```

**EDIT:** More details

```
public class ConfirmDialog {
    private final Context parent;
    private final AlertDialog dialog;    
    private String text;

    public ConfirmDialog(Context parent) {
        this.parent = parent;

        final EditText editTextfield = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.comment_text);
        editTextfield.setText(text);

        this.dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(parent)
                       .setView(LayoutInflater.from(parent).inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null));
                       .setTitle(R.string.title); // you can also pass the title if you want a different one each time you instanciate the dialog
                       .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                              setText(editTextfield.getText().toString());
                              removeDialog(DIALOG);
                           }
                        });
                       .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                              removeDialog(DIALOG);
                           }
                        })
                       .create();
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void show() {
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

(I coded it quickly in the StackOverflow editor, so there may be syntax errors)

Comment: Could you expand upon this please. Little confused. Not expended another class like this before. Thanks

Comment: Edited my answer with a quick implementation of what I mean. Customise to your needs.

Comment: Is the {removeDialog(DIALOG);} line not error as you have not passed anything for that or have I got confused again. Thanks

Comment: I don't know, I assumed it was a custom method of yours - you can use dialog.dismiss();

Comment: The code was wrapped in a CreateDialog method with a Switch. The DIALOG was stated at top of code as a int. 1 in this case. I used it like that as that is how I leanrt to do it within a class.

Comment: I have been able to add this and edit to work. It pops up and displays correctly. Onyl trouble I have is once I close it and try and reopen it I get the following Error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Answer (score 1):

Read the answer in this question "[Sharing-menu-bar between Activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788652/sharing-menu-bar-between-activities/8789018#8789018%22)

Even though requirement is different but solution can be used in your problem